# allow two network adapters to act as the same device

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, docking-station

I have three network adapters on my windows 10 laptop. An internal WIFI adapter, an internal Ethernet adapter, and an external docking hub. Currently each of these adapters act as a different device, with a different IP, making it hard to port forward for my device.

I would like  to make it so no matter which way I connect my laptop to the network, it uses the same IP. I would imagine this would be done by either passing the connection from each adapter to one adapter, or configure this in the router somehow. However, configuring via the router could prove difficult as its a Cox panoramic router and utilizes the `wifi.Cox.com` website, which is finicky at best

I have tried creating a network bridge via control panel between the two Ethernet devices but it came up with an error that said something along the lines of "there was a problem". I also took a look around both the router page, via its IPv4, and the cox website but could not find anything that stood out.

Comment: I cant advise how you would do it under Windows, but the general term for what you are attempting is channel bonding.

Comment: do you know anything about [NIC Teaming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/nic-teaming/nic-teaming). It came up while looking into channel bonding, and it seems promising although Windows doesn't support it for non-server builds

Comment: I cant help with this on Windows (but maybe others can).

Comment: @davidgo you cannot do channel bonding unless you can control both ends (which doesn't seem to be the case for the Cox router).

Comment: @dirkt Thats only partially correct.  In Linux there are (at least) 6 bonding modes you can use, some of which require support on both ends, and others which don't - as this is being used primarily for reliability rather then speed, "balance-alb" mode (adaptive load balancing for fault tolerance using ARP negotiation)  would be appropriate and does not require switch support.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible with your system infrastructure. I would advice to find a solution for the problem of the requirement of the network adapters to have the same IP. Might be easier...